# Files in folder /run/udev/data

Tags: centos, udev, jails

Does someone know, when and how the files in this folder `/run/udev/data` are generated.

I ask because I have a program, which needs udev in jail. But the version in jail is newer (version 208) than the version of my CentOS 6.6 system (version 147). The udev version in jail searches for files in directory `/run/udev/data`, but on CentOS 6.6, there is no such a directory.

Edit: To be more clear: I install an external software on my CentOS 6.6 System. This external software uses udev, but the udev version which is shipped with the software is newer than the software of my CentOS 6.6 system. This newer udev searches for `/run/udev` which isn't on my host system and because of this also not in jail.

Answer (score 3):

In older versions the udev database was located under /dev/.udev/db. In newer versions it is located under /run/udev/data. From a quick browsing it appears to me that also the contents has changed a bit, so not sure whether just copying around the files (or creating symbolic links) will work.

I have successfully copied /run/udev/data from a host (running systemd-udevd) into a container (not running systemd-udevd) However, libudev was the same version on both the host and inside the container. (This was just a proof of concepts. I'm not sure whether that results in a stable and secure system.)

To my understanding the udevd (systemd-udevd) writes the files. Other programs access them using libudev.